# A unique 'discount' challenge for a jQuery calculator

Tags: jquery, forms, calculator

I've been muddling through this one for a while...  I have three form fields: individuals, couples, total. This is a cost calculator for a conference registration.

A single person (#individuals) costs $50. A couple (#couples) costs $75.  There's a discount applied if there are more than 3 total people signing up. Each person costs $40 under the discount. So we count the total people, and if 3 or more people, apply a new price of $40 to each person. Before counting total people between #individuals and #couples fields, the value of #couples needs to be multiplied by two, since there are two people per couple. The new 'discounted' #individuals price is $40 and new #couple price is $80.

My question is simply "where have I gone wrong?".  Any insight is greatly appreciated.

My current code, which is yielding incorrect numbers in the #total field:

```
   $('#individuals').change(compute);
   $('#couples').change(compute);
   function compute() {
      var ind = $('#individuals').val(); // number of individuals
      var coup = $('#couples').val()*2; // number of people in a couple (2)
      var people = ind + coup; // add up the total people
      if (people >= 3) {    
        var a = $('#individuals').val()*40; // discount price of an individual
        var b = $('#couples').val()*80; // discount price of couple
      }
      else {
        var a = $('#individuals').val()*50; // normal price of an individual
        var b = $('#couples').val()*75; // normal price of couple
      }
      var total = a + b;
      $('#total').val(total);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. don't repeat yourself - only make one call to `$('#element').val()` for each field
2. use `parseInt(val, 10)` to ensure your numbers are numbers and not strings.  Your `ind` field is currently a string and will cause errors when you "concatenate" it to `coup`:

e.g.:

```
function compute() {
  var ind = parseInt($('#individuals').val(), 10); // number of individuals
  var coup = parseInt($('#couples').val(), 10);    // number of couples
  var people = ind + 2 * coup;                     // add up the total people
  var total;
  if (people >= 3) { 
    total = 40 * people;
  } else {
    total = 50 * ind + 75 * coup;
  }
  $('#total').val(total);
}

$('#individuals,#couples').on('change', compute);
```

Comment: Thank you - this works great and has helped me sort through some areas of ignorance on my part when it comes to jQuery.

Comment: please also see update which IMHO is a clearer way of expressing your "discount" logic.